# Angular 2 FormBuilder and ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, angular2-formbuilder

I'm trying to update nested data collected from a service. I display the database data in a html form by using the `*ngFor` to fill the input values.

When I try to submit this, it always gives me `null` because I haven't actually touched the fields. Weirdly enough when I enter new values for that field or edit the given value, it does pass them. In normal cases this would be exactly how I want it.

But in this case if I only edit the first field and `submit` the form, it will only pass the first field's value and give `null` for the other fields.

In other words it would be dangerous for me to overwrite the existing data with the form data because it would overwrite all by null except for the first one.

**--------- EDIT ----------**

The code underneath now works, using the FormBuilder. It generates these fields (picture below) by a loop that loops the main arrays length.

In clear language: the array contains a variable amount of objects.
For each object there's:

- a title (first inputfield)
- a header size (second input)
- a variable amount of paragraphs

and each group is closed with a `<hr>` tag.

You can also see that I fill up `each` input fields' `value` tag, using `*ngFor` (see html below).

Now the problem is that if I `submit` the form without changing any value, I get an array of objects with all the correct keys **but** all their values are set to `null` since I haven't actually edited the fields.

If I submit I would like to retrieve an array of objects **with** their values even if I haven't edited a single one.

Otherwise I would have to write a complex functionality to only overwrite the current data where the value `is not null`.

**So my actual question is:**

Is there a way to retrieve all the values even if I haven't edited (touched) a single field? Or should I use the other approach?

[image]

If I `submit` the form I get this (because I haven't actually edited something):

[image]

HTML:

```
<h3>Description</h3>
<form [formGroup]="colForm" (submit)="updateCol(colForm); $event.preventDefault()">
    <div class="margin-bottom-30" *ngFor="let col of overall_data.value.cols; let i=index">
        <div [formGroupName]="i">
            <div class="form-group" formGroupName="title">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" formControlName="text" name="text" value="{{ col.title.text }}">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" formControlName="size" name="size" min="1" max="5" value="{{ col.title.size }}">
            </div>
            <div formGroupName="body">
                <div formArrayName="paragraphs"> 
                    <div *ngFor="let p of col.body.paragraphs; let pi=index">
                        <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="pi">
                            <textarea class="form-control" formControlName="text" cols="30" rows="10" value="{{ p.text }}"></textarea>
                            <div *ngIf="p.classes" formArrayName="classes">
                                <div *ngFor="let class of p.classes">
                                    <input type="text" name="class" class="form-control" value="{{ class }}">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-custom" value="Save">
    </div>
</form>
```

TypeScript file:

```
export class AdminWebComponent implements OnInit {
    overall_data: any;
    id: string;
    errorMessage: string;
    colForm: FormArray = this._fb.array([]);

constructor(private _skillsService: SkillsService, private _fb: FormBuilder) {

    // work with form groups: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this._skillsService.getByKey('web')
    .subscribe(
        overall_data => this.overall_data = overall_data,
        error => this.errorMessage = error,
        () => { 
            this.id = this.overall_data['id'];

            // cols
            for (var i = 0; i < this.overall_data.value.cols.length; ++i) {
                this.colForm.push(this.initCols()) // in for loop so we can have a dynamic amount of cols
            }

            // charts

        }
    );
}

// init functions
initCols(): any {
    return this._fb.group({ // need to be called twice because array has 2 items, makes this dynamic?
        title: this._fb.group({ 
            text: [""], 
            size: [0]
        }),
        body: this._fb.group({
            paragraphs: this._fb.array([
                this.initParagraphs(),
                this.initParagraphs()
                ])
        })
    })
}
initParagraphs(): any {
    return this._fb.group({
        text: [""],
        classes: this._fb.array([])
    })
}


// update functions
updateCol(colForm: any): void {
    console.log(this.id);
    console.log(colForm.value);

    // this._skillsSevice()
    // .
}
```

------- **SOLVED** --------

It wasn't simple (for me) but it was really obvious what I had to do ...
I had to remove the `value binding` that I did in the `HTML` and instead fill the values with the formbuilder by using for loops.

It seems like trying to combine the formbuilder controls with values generated in the HTML isn't a good idea & not very logic. 
Better to handle my complex data in the TypeScript file rather than in the HTML.

TypeScript Adjustments:

```
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._skillsService.getByKey('web')
    .subscribe(
        overall_data => this.overall_data = <ISkills>overall_data,
        error => this.errorMessage = error,
        () => { 
            this.id = this.overall_data['id'];

            // cols
            for (var i = 0; i < this.overall_data.value.cols.length; ++i) {
                this.colForm.push(this.initCols(this.overall_data.value.cols[i])) // in for loop so we can have a dynamic amount of cols
            }

            // charts

        }
    );
}

// init functions
initCols(cols: ICols): any {
    // console.log(cols);
    return this._fb.group({ // need to be called twice because array has 2 items, makes this dynamic?
        title: this._fb.group({ 
            text: [ cols.title.text ], 
            size: [ cols.title.size ]
        }),
        body: this._fb.group({
            paragraphs: this.initParagraphs(cols.body.paragraphs)
        })
    })
}
initParagraphs(paragraphs: IParagraph[]): any {
    let arr: FormArray = this._fb.array([]);

    for (var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; ++i) {
        arr.push(
            this._fb.group({
                text: [ paragraphs[i].text ],
                classes: this._fb.array([ paragraphs[i].classes ])
            })
        )
    }
    return arr;
}
...
```

Comment: do u have wireframe of your expectation?

Comment: Can you please comment on why you don't initialize colForm as part of your ngOnInit itself rather than within the complete method of your _skillsService.getByKey('web') stream? Also have you thought of using [(ngModel)] to bind your form data to your component data? It feels like some code or explanation is missing here to understand what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I updated the question and provided the lay-out.

Comment: @BenDadsetan I wouldn't know how to bind that?

Comment: @BenDadsetan binding the fields to a new object also only binds if the field is touched or changed

Comment: I solved it :) Thanks for your time anyway!

Comment: Can I post your solution for the benefit of other viewers? You can then select your own answer as the right one.

Comment: @BenDadsetan sure, thank you :)

Comment: Auguste, you should answer it yourself, pull your answer out of the question and post it as an answer. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer